# How to retrieve e-mail using command line in Linux

Tags: linux, email, command-line

Is there a possibility to retrieve e-mails by command line in Linux?

I look for a solution to retrieve e-mails from a pop/imap server down to the local server for archiving purposes. It should run as a unobtrusive background process. Does anyone now about a possibility to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For IMAP synchronization you can use OfflineIMAP (http://www.offlineimap.org) and  isync (http://isync.sourceforge.net). For pop, there is fetchmail (www.fetchmail.info).

To run them in the background, you can use cron or systemd.